# Execute an existing Cocoa app with a python script

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

I'm trying to learn how to use python and pyObjC to automate application testing for our Cocoa -Objective C code base.

I have found plenty of examples on how to re-create an objective C app using pyObjC, however, this involves literally re writing the app in python using objective C Frameworks and classes. I can not find any examples of executing Cocoa apps or components with python or pyObjC.

I have a custom framework. It contains an WindowController that is the entry point for an editor. When I initialize this in a cocoa app and click a button it appears and I can interact with it.

Following the example here, [pyObjC example](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-20-probing-cocoa-with-pyobjc.html), I can successfully initialize my window controller and make it appear , however, I can not interact with any control, including the close window button.

My snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Opens the Window

import time
from Foundation import *

bundle = NSBundle.bundleWithPath_('/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework')
controller = bundle.classNamed_('MyController').alloc().initWithWindowNibName_('MyWindow')
controller.showWindow_(0)

# Hold the window open for a bit
time.sleep(20.0)
```

I have also tried to add:

```
from AppKit import *
NSApplicationLoad()
True
```

thinking maybe that would help but no. I'm sure the missing piece is that the actual Cocoa app is never being executed, but I can't seem to find the solution.

My goal here isn't to rewrite Objective C using python.. Its to help our QA people automate some inter app testing.

Any Guidance appreciated.

Comment: you most certainly *do not* have to "Rewrite" an application in python to use PyObjC. you can happily use PyObjeC insite an existing objective-C application.

Comment: Ahh. Isn't that the inverse of what I'm trying to do? I don't think I need to execute python code in my objective C apps, I need to execute functional portions of Cocoa apps with python scripts.

Comment: mkay, `time.sleep(20.0)` is going to suspend your application so obviously you wont be able to interact with it while it is sleeping. You need to start the main runloop for the application. `NSApplicationMain()` needs to be called after `NSApplicationLoad()` I believe.

Comment: I put sleep there because for some reason the window would only appear for a second in the script, but when I entered the same code in the terminal it remained until I typed exit()

Comment: I understand why you put it there, but thats not how sleep works. when your process sleeps it wont get any events or do any sort of processing so it is worthless to put there for your purposes.

Comment: BTW Xcode/Cocoa has some nice frameworks for automated testing. dont know what those are lacking that requires you to attempt this.

Comment: @BradAllred Thanks. I just started looking into those awhile ago. There is a Test Automator in instruments for IOS only, but unfortunately , almost all my work is OSX. I am also looking at the automator project in Xcode using the automator.app. Your right though. Probably much better solution.